# May I Carry a Power Bank from Vancouver CA to Frankfurt DE?

Tags: canada, hand-luggage, lufthansa, prohibited-items, batteries

Can I carry power bank in carry-on on Lufthansa airplane? I have RavPower Model: RP-PB19, Capacity: 55.5Wh.

Answer (score 3):

Lufthansa considers powerbanks to be spare lithium batteries and thus they may be carried in your carry-on and only in your carry-on.